# How to connect to oracle legacy database using cx_oracle django package?

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

My database settings to connect to legacy oracle database backend are

`DATABASES = {
    'bannerdb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'host:port/service_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },`

I am using this command to run create models.py file using

`python manage.py inspectdb --database=bannerdb >models.py`

My question is the following

- when I run the `inspectdb` command as mentioned above it creates an empty `models.py` file as

  ```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals
   from django.db import models
  ```

I did lot research but was unable to find a way to create `models.py` file for the oracle database backend with cx_oracle package, please help. I am a new bee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue, unlike connecting with other databases (postgres, mysql etc) using django, to access oracle legacy database the models.py file needs to be created manually. 
In my case `python manage.py inspectdb --database=bannerdb >models.py` did not work. I created the models.py file as

```
class table_name(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=9, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        db_table="table_name_oracle_database"
```

Full explanation of using oracle database back end is here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/vasiliev-django-100257.html.